# FFMPEG HLS video speed is too fast

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I am trying to make a `.m3u8` hls playlist locally on my computer. I am using Windows 7, 32 bit.

I am a begginner of `FFMPEG`, and finally I combined some commands into this:

```
ffmpeg -re -rtbufsize 999999k -y -f dshow -video_size 640x360 -r 15 -i video="ManyCam Virtual Webcam" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -profile:v main -maxrate 999999k -bufsize 99999k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -g 3 -hls_list_size 2 -hls_wrap 0 -start_number 1 D:\\stream\stream.m3u8 -tune zerolatency
```

The problem is that while playing the m3u8 playlist with VLC or a HLS player, the video speed is faster than normal.

If you need more info, please comment.

**EDIT**

If I play one of the `.ts` files, the problem is the same.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You've specified a input rate of 15. Try a)removing that flag, b)setting it to a lower value

Comment: Also, shift the zerolatency to before the output name.